# MySQL: already installed but still in dependencies list with an inferior version

Tags: mysql, centos, dependencies

I'm trying to install *GDAL* on my **CentOS server** to be able to make some GIS operations, but I'm having a lot of problems with MySQL that I can't figure out...

Here are the commands I tried, without success.

I tried a simple:

```
# yum install gdal
```

- First, **the GDAL version is 1.4 (the last released one is 1.9)**
- Then, **I see in the dependencies list `mysql`**. But I have `mysql` already installed, from another repository (*remi*), with a newer version than the one suggested by `yum`... Is it a problem of architecture (yum suggests i386)?
- I risked a **yes**, but still impossible to install it!

Here's the error I have.

```
Transaction Check Error:
package mysql-5.5.28-1.el5.remi.x86_64 (which is newer than mysql-5.0.95-1.el5_7.1.i386) is already installed
```

---

Then, I tried to install it from sources with last version available (1.9.2). I downloaded the GDAL tar.gz, extracted the files and installed it like following:

```
# tar -xzf gdal-1.9.2.tar.gz
# ./configure --with-static-proj4=/usr/local/lib --with-threads --with-libtiff=internal --with-geotiff=internal --with-jpeg=internal --with-gif=internal --with-png=internal --with-libz=internal
# make
# make install
```

But during the make, I have some strange errors displaying, about **RegisterOGRMySQL**, that I can't understand:

```
chmod a+x gdal-config
/bin/sh /home/benjamin/gdal-1.9.2/libtool --mode=link    g++  gdalinfo.lo  /home/benjamin/gdal-1.9.2/libgdal.la  -o gdalinfo
libtool: link: g++ .libs/gdalinfo.o -o .libs/gdalinfo  /home/benjamin/gdal-1.9.2/.libs/libgdal.so -L/usr/local/lib/lib -L/usr/kerberos/lib64 -lproj -lsqlite3 /usr/lib64/libexpat.so -lpthread -lrt -lcurl -ldl -lgssapi_krb5 -lkrb5 -lk5crypto -lcom_err -lidn -lssl -lcrypto -lz  -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/local/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/usr/lib64
/home/benjamin/gdal-1.9.2/.libs/libgdal.so: undefined reference to `RegisterOGRMySQL'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [gdalinfo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/benjamin/gdal-1.9.2/apps'
make: *** [apps-target] Error 2
```

Has anyone a solution? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem, which was just an architecture problem actually (and it took me a whole week to figure it out...), using:

```
yum install gdal.x86_64
```

(and using elgis repository to have a more recent version)